# How can I send parameter with {{ }} in laravel's @include()

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to send route as parameter in @include() in Laravel.
I'm trying to send parameter with {{ }} to put it as href value, but I got error message. Is there a way to put '{{ }}' in string?

This is what causes error:

```
@include('includes.content.single-article', ['href' => '{{ route('article') }}'])
```

It should look like that in single-article.blade.php:

```
<a class="card-link btn btn-warning" href="{{ $href }}">more<span class="icon icon-plus"></span></a>
```

And it should work like that:

```
    <a class="card-link btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('article') }}">more<span class="icon icon-plus"></span></a>
```

Error I got:

ParseError
syntax error, unexpected 'article' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

Comment: By using `@include` you're already within the blade parser/php block, so just remove the `{{ }}` surrounding the route.

Comment: Based on the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews), you should not use `{{ }}` in PHP array: `@include('includes.content.single-article', ['href' => route('article')])`

Comment: I guess one of you two could make an answer, because this is the problem

Comment: Yes! Removing `{{ }}` in parameter solves the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send variable. `@include` is a "copy/paste" (same `@extend`).

just do this:

```
@php($href=route("article"))
@include("includes.content.single-article")
```

and that's all. Now your blade `includes.content.single-article` knows the value for `$href`.

And if you really need a variable only for this blade

```
@include("catalog.task.foo", ["href" => route("purchase.provider")])
```

When you use a blade directive, you are in `PHP` context, don't use `"` if you don't need string.

you can

```
@include("catalog.task.foo", ["href" => 45+58])
```

And will do math

Comment: There is a difference. By passing the variable, it will only be available in the included view.